# HomeKit show no homes in WatchOS 2

Tags: watchos-2, homekit

WatchKit app using WatchOS2 with HomeKit capabilities, but 
HMHomeManager return with no homes (after homeManagerDidUpdateHomes is called).

The corresponding iOS app works fine, and show the homes.

Comment: Your apple watch might be homeless.. :)

Comment: you mean homekit does not match device and watch?

Comment: It was a simple joke. Yes it should match but it might be a problem with watchOS 2 being a beta version

Comment: @david72 Hi david! Did you find any solution to get added home and rooms from HomeKit to watch kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work on real watch but not in simulator